# Is sending a message through Android push notifications idempotent (exactly once delivery)?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I am curious what the case is for both GCM and FCM - I see that GCM is being deprecated but this will still be relevant until it is.